# geom_bar(position="dodge") in Python ggplot library

Tags: python, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to plot a bar chart with the dodge feature. In R's ggplot2 library, I could accomplish this using

```
geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

Is there a way to do this in yhat's ggplot library as well? If not, what's the best way to do this using the same ggplot design?

[image]

Comment: I've also come across this. It seems that the position keyword doesn't work.